# Spring Boot Oracle Rest JdbcTemplate Gradle app with in-memory H2 for unit tests

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, h2, jdbctemplate

I'm building a Spring Boot REST app for an existing Oracle database, and due to multiple factors, am constrained to using JdbcTemplate instead of JPA. I'm trying to use an in-memory H2 database for the unit tests, but am having difficulty with its configuration.

App code compiles and runs fine, successfully connecting to (and returning Query results from) the Oracle db using:

```
gradle clean bootRun -x test
```

But when I try to run just the tests:

```
gradle clean test
```

I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select * from schema_name.persons where id = ?]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "persons" not found; SQL statement: select * from schema_name.persons where id = ? [42102-192]
```

I have an application.properties for the prod instance that looks like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdcbc:oracle:thin:@(connection details...)
spring.datasource.username=(prod oracle db username)
spring.datasource.password=(prod oracle db password)
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

and an application-test.properties that looks like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS schema_name;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;MODE=Oracle
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

Spring Boot picks up the correct datasource attributes, as it's obviously connecting to the Oracle DB when excluding the test classes in bootRun, and conversely, trying to connect to the H2 database when I solely try to run the tests.

I think the issue is related to the schema and table combo in H2 vs. in Oracle, but can't figure out where the disconnect is.  I added in the

```
INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS schema_name
```

to try to address this, but I seem to get the same error either way. Here's the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)  
@SpringBootTest()  
@ActiveProfiles("test")  
public class PersonServiceTest {  

@Autowired  
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Before
public void setup() throws ScriptException, SQLException {
  ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection(),
    new ClassPathResource("scripts/create/fake_persons.sql");
  ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection(),
    new ClassPathResource("scripts/insert/fake_persons.sql");
}

@After
public void teardown() throws ScriptException, SQLException {
  ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection(),
    new ClassPathResource("scripts/drop/fake_persons.sql");
}

@Autowired
private IPersonDao personDao;

private Person testPerson;

@Test
public void getPersonByIdTest(){
  testPerson = personDao.getPersonById(1234);
  assertEquals("Person named John should have been returned", true, testPerson.getFirstName() == "John");
}

}
```

Here's the SQL I'm using to create the table:

```
create table schema_name.persons (
LASTNAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
NOTES VARCHAR(100),
ID INT NOT NULL);
```

And here's how I populate it:

```
insert into schema_name.persons (
LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,NOTES,ID
) values (
'Doe','John','Here are some notes about this person', 1234
);
```

The query (in the Java PersonDao class) for getPersonById is:

```
Select * from schema_name.persons where id = ?
```

And is executed successfully against the Prod db using getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject() method. But I can't get past the schema/table issue when running it against the in-memory database.

Comment: did you tried to put a breakpoint on `setup()` method to check why your table won't creates?

Comment: @Spara thank you for your comment, as it set me down the right path! It turns out I made a mistake in the table naming for the test database, so of course when the Autowired service tried to find the _correct_ table name, it could not. The incorrectly named table had been there all along... dumb mistake on my part!